# Effect of default argument promotions on wchar_t

Tags: c, variadic-functions, wchar-t, integer-promotion

I am a bit confused about how default argument promotions effect `wchar_t`.

I understand that `char` is promoted to `int`, and therefore I have to supply `int` as the second parameter of `va_arg`, otherwise I may (GCC) or may not (MSVC) get an error, as demonstrated by the `"%c"` example below.

So, I thought that - analogically - I should take into account some similar promotion in case of `wchar_t`, and read the definitions of the relevant types in the C99 standard:

> 7.17 `wchar_t` ... is an integer type whose range of values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended
> character set specified among the supported locales; the null
> character shall have the code value zero. Each member of the basic
> character set shall have a code value equal to its value when used as
> the lone character in an integer character constant if an
> implementation does not define `__STDC_MB_MIGHT_NEQ_WC__`.
>
> 7.24.1 `wint_t` ... is an integer type **unchanged by default argument promotions** that can hold any value corresponding to members of the
> extended character set, as well as at least one value that does not
> correspond to any member of the extended character set (see `WEOF`
> below).

It is clear to me that `wint_t` is not promoted to anything, and I suspect but do not know for sure that `wchar_t` is not promoted either.

I tried fetching arguments with `va_arg` as `wchar_t`, `wint_t` and `int`, and all of these worked, however, this may have happened because of luck:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>

void print( char const* format, ... );

int main()
{
    printf( "char == %zu, int == %zu, wchar_t == %zu, wint_t == %zu.\n",
        sizeof( char ), sizeof( int ), sizeof( wchar_t ), sizeof( wint_t ) );
        // MSVC x86: char == 1, int == 4, wchar_t == 2, wint_t == 2.
        // MSVC x64: char == 1, int == 4, wchar_t == 2, wint_t == 2.
        // GCC  x64: char == 1, int == 4, wchar_t == 4, wint_t == 4.

    char charA = 'A';
    print( "%c", charA );

    wchar_t wchar_tA = L'A';
    print( "%lc", wchar_tA );

    printf( "\n" );
}

void print( char const* format, ... )
{
    va_list arguments;
    va_start( arguments, format );
    if( strcmp( format, "%c" ) == 0 ) {
        // char c = va_arg( arguments, char );     // -> Bad (1)
        char c = va_arg( arguments, int );         // -> Good
        putchar( ( int ) c );
    } else if( strcmp( format, "%lc" ) == 0 ) {
        wchar_t w = va_arg( arguments, wchar_t );  // -> Good
        // wint_t w = va_arg( arguments, wint_t ); // -> Good
        // int w = va_arg( arguments, int );       // -> Good
        putwchar( ( wchar_t ) w );
    }
    va_end( arguments );
}

// (1) GCC prints:
//       warning: 'char' is promoted to 'int' when passed through '...'
//       note: (so you should pass 'int' not 'char' to 'va_arg')
//     Running the program prints:
//       Illegal instruction
```

The question: Which of the three lines containing `va_arg` in the `else if` block is the correct, standard-compliant one?

Comment: C99 has not been the C language standard for some time now.  It gave way to C11,  current is C17, and C23 is anticipated Real Soon Now.

Comment: I agree with your thinking that `va_arg(args, wint_t)` would be best.

Comment: (a) The C standard does not necessarily provide a solution for all problems. (b) If `wchar_t` is the same width as `int`, then `wint_t` must be wider, so using `wint_t` in `va_arg` to fetch a `wchar_t` is wrong. Using `int` is likely to work in most circumstances.

Comment: I agree with Eric: `int w = va_arg(arguments, int);` is probably your "best bet".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought that - analogically - I should take into account some similar promotion in case of `wchar_t`,

Yes, the type you specify to the `va_arg()` macro must be compatible with the type of the corresponding actual argument, as promoted according to the default argument promotions, except that you can interchange signed and unsigned versions of the same type as long as both can represent the actual value, and you can interchange `void *` and `char *`.

> It is clear to me that `wint_t` is not promoted to anything,

Yes, inasmuch as I take you to mean *by the default argument promotions*, the specifications say that explicitly.

> and I suspect but do not know for sure that `wchar_t` is not promoted either.

It is not safe to assume that `wchar_t` is unchanged by the default argument promotions.  If it is neither `int` nor `unsigned int` but its integer conversion rank is less than or equal to that of `int`, then it is affected.  Otherwise not.  C does not specify which case applies, and that may vary from implementation to implementation.

Note also that although integer conversion rank is related to the size of a representation of the type (narrow is, generally, lower), it is a distinct concept, and in principle, you cannot reliably judge based on size.

---

> Which of the three lines containing `va_arg` in the else if block is the correct, standard-compliant one?

It depends on your implementation.  There is no available alternative that is certain to be correct for every conforming implementation, because the spec does not constrain `wchar_t` sufficiently for that.  But of the three, **this one is your best bet**:

> ```
>         // int w = va_arg( arguments, int );       // -> Good
> ```

That covers you in all remotely likely variations of `wchar_t` being promoted to a different type via the default argument promotions.  It is definitely correct when `wchar_t` is `int`.  And it's fine if `wchar_t` is `unsigned int`, as long as the actual value of the argument does not exceed `INT_MAX`.

It would be incorrect for an implementation in which `wchar_t` had greater integer conversion rank than `int`, but I do not know any implementation with that characteristic, and I don't expect ever to see one.

In contrast, **this one is unsafe**:

> ```
>         wchar_t w = va_arg( arguments, wchar_t );  // -> Good
> ```

It is ok if `wchar_t` is `int` or `unsigned int`, but the previous is also good in that case (except if `wchar_t` is `unsigned int` and the argument value exceeds `INT_MAX`).  This would be the only correct alternative for an implementation where `wchar_t` had greater integer conversion rank than `int` and was not the same as `wint_t`, but again, I don't expect ever to see such an implementation. But otherwise, it is ***wrong*** when `wchar_t` has integer conversion rank less than or equal to that of `int`, and that is a characteristic of some real-world implementations.

And **this one is less safe than the `int` alternative:**

> ```
>         // wint_t w = va_arg( arguments, wint_t ); // -> Good
> ```

If `wint_t` happens to be `int` then it is equivalent to the `int` variation, of course.  But if it happens to be neither `int` nor `unsigned int` nor `wchar_t`, however, then it is definitely wrong, whether `wchar_t` is affected by the integer promotions or not.